# Get long format in a special way

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, melt

I have a dataset that is quite in a wide-format and I want it to be in a long format. Usually I use melt for that cases but here I don't know if this will work. That's my dataset:

```
> Data <-
+   data.table(
+     ID = 1:6,
+     N1 = round(rnorm(6)),
+     E1 = round(rnorm(6)),
+     N2 = round(rnorm(6, 5)),
+     E2 = round(rnorm(6, 5)),
+     Class1 = 1,
+     Class2 = 2
+   )
> 
> Data
   ID N1 E1 N2 E2 Class1 Class2
1:  1  0  0  4  5      1      2
2:  2 -1  0  5  5      1      2
3:  3  0 -1  5  5      1      2
4:  4  1  0  5  5      1      2
5:  5 -1 -1  4  7      1      2
6:  6 -2 -1  6  6      1      2
```

My desired dataset is that one:

```
> Data.Long <- 
+   rbind(
+     Data[, .(ID, N = N1, E = E1, Class = Class1)],
+     Data[, .(ID, N = N2, E = E2, Class = Class2)]
+   )
> Data.Long
    ID  N  E Class
 1:  1  0  0     1
 2:  2 -1  0     1
 3:  3  0 -1     1
 4:  4  1  0     1
 5:  5 -1 -1     1
 6:  6 -2 -1     1
 7:  1  4  5     2
 8:  2  5  5     2
 9:  3  5  5     2
10:  4  5  5     2
11:  5  4  7     2
12:  6  6  6     2
```

For this case my attempt with `rbind` and variable selection is quite OK. But in my real dataset I have more variables like `ID` and probably I have more than two classes. Can you think of a better code that won't be repetitive even if there are many classes?

Comment: it's not quite clear about the "Class": in your original dataset, `Class1` column equals `1` for all records, `Class2` always equals `2` etc. - is that right?

Comment: No not always, that's only in this minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(Data, 
                    cols = -ID,
                    names_to = '.value',
                    names_pattern = '([A-Za-z]+)') 

#      ID     N     E Class
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0     0     1
# 2     1     5     6     2
# 3     2    -1    -2     1
# 4     2     6     6     2
# 5     3     2     0     1
# 6     3     6     5     2
# 7     4     0     0     1
# 8     4     4     6     2
# 9     5    -2     1     1
#10     5     5     6     2
#11     6    -1     0     1
#12     6     6     5     2
```

`.value` has a special meaning in `pivot_longer` which means that the new columns in the long format would have names from the original column names. How are those name derived is defined using `names_pattern` argument. In `names_pattern` we mentioned that extract all the characters (`[A-Za-z]+`) from the name as new name. So `N1`, `N2` become `N` and they are combined into one column. Same happens with `E1`, `E2` and `Class1`, `Class2` pair.

Comment: Great, thank you! Could you explain this a bit please? `names_pattern` is a regex for one ore more letters (why?) and what does `'.value'` in `names_to` do?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include some explanation.